# How to pass callback to child LWC (lightning web component)?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a parent component like

```js
export default class Parent extends LightningElement {
   onResult() {
      this.doSomething();
   }
}

<template>
    <c-child result-callback={onResult}></c-child>
</template>
```

and a child component:

```js
export default class Child extends LightningElement {
   @api resultCallback;

   onClick() {
      this.resultCallback();
   }
}

<template>
    <button onclick={onClick}>click me</button>
</template>
```

The issue seems to be that when `this.resultCallback()` runs, which calls the parent's `onResult` method, `this` is still the child component.

LWCs seem to magically autobind methods, so I'm not sure if this a LWC bug or if I'm missing something.

How does a parent element pass a callback to a child LWC?

Comment: This approach to parent-child communication comes with some caveats. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288057 and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/381234

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have to bind the method before passing it to the child.

```
Ex1: arrow function is auto bind.

export default class Parent extends LightningElement {

   onResult = () => {
      this.doSomething();
   }
}
----
<template>
    <c-child result-callback={onResult}></c-child>
</template>
```

```
Ex2: binding it in the constructor.

export default class Parent extends LightningElement {
   result = this.onResult.bind(this)

   onResult() {
      this.doSomething();
   }
}
----
<template>
    <c-child result-callback={result}></c-child>
</template>
```

Comment: oh nice, I didn't realize LWCs supported fat arrow. Thanks!

Comment: hi Andrius Satraitis, Could you explain for me why use arrow function ? I don't undertand about it

Comment: @ptdung0312 Arrow functions do not have their own `this`. See: [No separate this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)