# Better practice for passing JS methods from Parent to Child in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, customevent

What is the better practice for passing/using methods from a Parent LWC to a Child LWC.

Option 1: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/291221/3901

Option 2: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch

These both feel like they accomplish the same outcome. Was just curious which is the better practice

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate, but this thread covers similar ground: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288057

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events are the best practice for communicating from child to parent, and attributes for passing data from parent to children. It is unusual to use the first link's design pattern, since you'd normally use an event for this purpose, and the second link doesn't work if you want to talk about passing data from the parent to children (events only go up the DOM, not down). Aside from that, a parent can always query a child (`this.template.querySelector('c-child')`) to call an `@api` exposed method:

```
parentMethod() {
  this.template.querySelector('c-child').someMethod();
}
```

---

```
@api someMethod() { // on child
  console.log('I was called!');
}
```

---

I would advise against using the callback design, as it forces the child to check if there is a parent to notify first, and events can notify multiple upstream parents at once, which is not possible with the callback design.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox this is exactly what I was looking for.